# Qthread - sleep till event

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I want a thread that sleeps as long as a signal is triggered in my programm.
I created a Qthread and added my class to it

```
QThread* serialthread = new QThread;
Serial*  serial = new Serial();
serial->moveToThread(serialthread);
connect(serial, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
connect(serialthread, SIGNAL(started()), serial, SLOT(process));
connect(serial, SIGNAL(finished()), serialthread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(serial, SIGNAL(finished()), serial, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(serialthread, SIGNAL(finished()), serialthread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
serialthread->start();
```

The function serial::sendRequest() of my class should be triggered by a signal.
The other time I want the thread so sleep without wasting CPU-Time.

Comment: Simply connecting the _slot_ `sendRequest()` to a singal should work. What are your specific problems?

Comment: my problem is that didn't know that qthread::run starts a event loop that doenst burn cpu. but now I know it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread is already sleeping and not wasting any CPU time when there's no work for it to do. You don't need to do anything special to get that behavior. It's how the default implementation of `QThread::run` behaves: it starts an event loop. When the event loop has no events to handle, it sleeps, waiting for more events.